# Entity Framework Date Parsing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to do a LINQ to Entities query (am still very new with EF and am learning where it is diff than LinqToSQL) and am trying to do something like this:

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);

Apps = (from app in context.Instances
                 where app.ReleaseDate.Date == begin
                 select new ScalpApp
                 {
                 Image = app.Image,
                 PublisherName = app.PublisherName,
                 }).ToList();
```

while this works in LinqPad, it doesn't in my code.  The thrown exception is:

> ```
> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
> ```
>
> Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

How do I do this in LinqToEF?  The field in the DB is a full DateTime (with timecode) and I am trying to parse based on date only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cann't simple use 'app.ReleaseDate.Data', but you can:

```
var begin = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
var end = begin.AddHours(24);

Apps = (from app in context.Instances
             where 
               (app.ReleaseDate >= begin) and
               (app.ReleaseDate < end)
             select new ScalpApp
             {
             Image = app.Image,
             PublisherName = app.PublisherName,
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yup, this is excatly where I ended up having to go.  A bit annoyed, but oh well.  Though, I did begin.AddDays(1).

Answer (score 3):

This one may even use index on date field:

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2);

Apps = (from app in context.Instances
             where 
               (app.ReleaseDate >= begin) and
               (app.ReleaseDate < end)
             select new ScalpApp
             {
             Image = app.Image,
             PublisherName = app.PublisherName,
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

EF cannot translate getting `Date` part of `DateTime` into SQL code. But it has [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which can be translated into canonical TruncateTime function:

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);

Apps = (from app in context.Instances
        where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(app.ReleaseDate) == begin
        select new ScalpApp {
            Image = app.Image,
            PublisherName = app.PublisherName,
        }).ToList();
```